# Encryption of JSON request body from React JS client side and decryption of the request body in the backend Laravel

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, encryption

I have a project which has its client side in React JS and the API server in PHP Laravel. I need a way to encrypt the JSON data sent in the request body of an API from the React client side and decrypt it in the Laravel backend to get the information sent in the request body. This is basically for security reasons so that someone with a bad intention can not modify the request data sent with the API from browser's developer tab or elsewhere. Is there any way/algorithm for both React and Laravel in which data can be encrypted in the React client side and decrypted with same algorithm in the Laravel backend? Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Could you please explain more or give a use case? I think you may be thinking about it in the wrong way. I say this because the "encryption key" that would be used to encrypt data in the frontend unless it is static will and would always be accessible. You also achieve this in your standard https connection I believe with TLS. TLS being transport layer security. Where public and private keys are handled between the server and client and the data is encrypted. Without this none of use would be able to our amazon items...

Comment: Relying on encryption this way doesn't make much sense. Since Javascripts runs on the client someone can always interfere with the data that's being put in a request. The solution is to sanitize and validate any JSON that the client sends on the server, and making sure you know who the client is.

Comment: You can however, use a JWT token to encrypt json messages encrypted with a specific algorithm and signature. Which is probably what you mean. This is something that is typically used in a API request.

Comment: There are also things built into laravel to assist with some of these issues like CSRF tokens, passport, sanctum, session tokens/keys, validation, middleware...

Comment: @amac let's say I have some JSON data to send in the request body like this 
{
"product_id": 1,
"price": 100
}

I want to encrypt this JSON so that someone can not modify these information like modifying the price or else. This JSON gets encrypted to a string and the encrypted string gets decrypted in Laravel backend to retrieve the information from the JSON.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware by saying "validate any JSON" do you mean to say using some authentication mechanism like JWT to let the server know who is making the request?

Comment: No he is saying validate it before sending it and also after. You can't obfuscate that from the client man. They have the same access you do. You can try, but at the end of the day they can find whatever key or tool you are using on the client end to encrypt your data. That is why there are session, tokens, csrf tokens, etc.. You have to believe that the user on the other end is who they say they are to some degree.

Comment: You are getting into a realm that is far and beyond the typical use case and I would guess that you are overcomplicating the concept. You could mfa every request etc, use DEK, or some piped encryption logic, IDK... I have done tons of work in healthcare in the HIPPA realm is this is pretty OTT to me. We validate data on both sides, use encryption at rest and transit (TLS), change keys, sanitize. They only other thing I could say is reduce data points. By that I mean don't send enough data that can cause an issue. Only enough that is need at that moment.

Comment: @amac so how to validate the data before sending it and also after sending?

Comment: Absolutely, make sure they are injecting anything into the request that should not be there. Also on the other end in your controllers ensure you are only accepting data keys that you are expecting. this is all sanitizing the request. for instance if your controller finds a key that is called malicious_id and it is filled with SQL statements. It throws an error 422 validation exception.

Comment: This may seem a little obvious, but here goes. Why are you sending the price? You or rather your database knows what the price of `product_id = 1` is. All you need to send is `Product=1` You know who the buyer is, they are the logged in person/company. The price is either on the product table or a customer_price table if you are being a bit clever with pricing

Comment: I think OP or just my thinking, he maybe utilizing React for a single page application. Which could mean that the initial data was loaded as soon as possible. Which, in your example @RiggsFolly the product price or stock value could change if that data is not synced with the backend. So there is a possible conundrum, if the application was "sourcing" prods/shares/whatever's value in realtime (websocket integrations, possibly) and the backend keeps the last value from the last processed transaction. Which could make sense in certain cases, but means the validity of that data is key.

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is an overall price calculation over the price sent in the request body(like tax, packaging charge etc) and some other logic for which sending the price of the product to the backend is necessary with the API. I am looking for a way in which the whole JSON data is converted to a string first(which I can do from the React frontend) and then encrypted using some algorithm and sent to the Laravel backend. Backend app then decrypts it to receive the actual data sent in the request body and processes it.

Comment: Please remember, everything you do in JS on the browser can be stopped, intercepted, negated, etc by even simple users. The experts can do much worse

Answer (score 0):

Assuming authentication is done right and you have protection against CSRF, using SSL (https) on the connection to the backend should provide the encryption you need.